# Submitting html form to SQL using PHP, getting ERROR 500

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a basic html form as follows:

```
<form class="blogPost" action="../php/action_page.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Type your blog post</legend>

    <br>Title <br>
    <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Witty Title?">
</br>
     <br>Post <br>
    <input name="post" type="text" placeholder="Write something clever!">
  </br>

  </fieldset>
<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

However when I pass it through the following php script I get a 500 ERROR in the browser.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';


$title = $_POST["title"];
$post = $_POST["post"];


try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "INSERT INTO blog_posts (title, post)
        VALUES ('$title', '$post')";

$conn->exec($sql);

            echo "New record created successfully";
}

catch (PDOException $pe) {
  echo "Couldn't connect to the database $dbname: " . $pe->getMessage() .
      ". </br>Record NOT created.";
}

$conn = null;
 ?>
```

This is following the PDO example posted on w3schools.com

Comment: suggestion.. start with a simple query and see if your PHP works

Comment: agreed. you should test each individual part separately and pinpoint exactly where the error gets thrown

Comment: you should also consider checking your php error logs and server error logs. do a little googling to find out the file path to your error logs (based on which type of server you are running - e.g. apache - and what your OS is)

Comment: `error_reporting E_ALL | E_STRICT `
`display_error On`

put this on `php.ini` it will show errors. it should be done Development enviourment.

Comment: whats in the logs?

Comment: is your action path correct?

Comment: show your directory. Where you put `php` and `view` file.

Comment: 'view' file? the action path is correct

Comment: add this `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your PHP file just before the include. and comment everything below and just add `print_r($_REQUEST);`